# Polynomial vs. pseudo-polynomial complexity for an algorithm with a graph as input

Tags: algorithm, graph, big-o, complexity-theory

When analyzing the complexity of an algorithm with a graph as input I have a hard time distinguish between polynomial runtime and pseudo-polynomial runtime.

The graph has |A| arcs and |V| vertices. The complexity of the algorithm is O(|A|*K^2) where K is some constant.

Is the complexity polynomial or pseudo-polynomial? And does it depend on whether the graph is specified as an adjacency list or an adjacency matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: The algorithm is definitely polynomial (and thus pseudo-polynomial) for adjacency lists, for adjacency matrices it depends on how 'dense' the graph is.

#### First of all, what is the definition of pseudo-polynomial or polynomial based on?

To formulate an algorithm, we need some way to encode the input in a machine-readable form. In the most theoretical version, this is meant to be the input for a Turing machine. If we have a graph with `n` vertices and `m` edges, we could write the following representation (similar to an edge list):

`n#u1,v1#u2,v2#...#um,vm`

where `ui` is the number of the start vertex and `vi` is the number of the end vertex of the `i`-th edge.

If we use a binary representation of the numbers (i.e. the number `k` takes up O(log k) space), then our whole graph can be represented as an input word of length L = O(log n * m)

If we use a unary representation, our input word has length L = O(n * m).

Polynomial (or pseudo-polynomial) means that your algorithm takes at most O(L^k) time for some fixed k, if our input numbers are represented as binary (or unary) numbers.

#### Back to your question

Your algorithm has runtime O(m) (the constant can be left out in Big-O notation), which is definitely polynomial (with k = 1) for adjacency lists (which use O(log n * m) space).

For adjacency matrices (which use O(n²) space), this only works if we have some asymptotic lower bound on the number of edges, but definitely if we have at least Ω(n) edges (for example if the graph is connected).

Comment: Thank you! I'm to sure I understand the representation. How is ui the number of the start vertex and vi is the number of the end vertex?

Comment: I should have formulated it more clearly: ui is the start vertex and vi the end vertex of the i-th edge/arc